In the local $U(1)$ symmetry , does the inverse projection map of each point is onto the tangent plane at the point?
Does a $U(1)$ local symmetry on a non-flat spacetime, say a sphere, imply that a point on the sphere is equivalent to a circle (corresponding to the phase) on the tangent space to that point?
Does this circle necessarily on the tangent space or is it only a special case? I mean can we imagine any other more general fibration like the Hopf fibration mapping?
